# O que esta expressão quer dizer?

Tags: python-3.x

Estou tentando instalar e usar o minio: `https://github.com/minio/minio`, e instalei o `https://github.com/py-pa/django-minio-storage` para user como storage no meu projeto do djando. Porém quando salvo uma image está me dando o seguinte erro:

```
File "/home/developer/.virtualenvs/store/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 358, in get_storage_class
    return import_string(import_path or settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE)
  File "/home/developer/.virtualenvs/store/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/home/developer/.virtualenvs/store/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 661, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 767, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 727, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/developer/.virtualenvs/store/lib/python3.5/site-packages/minio_storage/storage.py", line 52
    **kwargs,
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Que está nessa parte do código:

```
37     def __init__(                                                               
 38         self,                                                                   
 39         minio_client: minio.Minio,                                              
 40         bucket_name: str,                                                       
 41         *,                                                                      
 42         base_url: T.Optional[str] = None,                                       
 43         file_class=None,                                                        
 44         auto_create_bucket: bool = False,                                       
 45         presign_urls: bool = False,                                             
 46         auto_create_policy: bool = False,                                       
 47         policy_type: T.Optional[Policy] = None,                                 
 48         object_metadata: T.Optional[T.Dict[str, str]] = None,                   
 49         backup_format: T.Optional[str] = None,                                  
 50         backup_bucket: T.Optional[str] = None,                                  
 51         assume_bucket_exists: bool = False,                                     
 52         **kwargs,                                                      
 53     ):
```

Então retirei a vírgula e o erro parou de cair ali, mas aconteceu em outros lugares:

`raise OSError(f"The bucket {self.bucket_name} does not exist")`

Aqui eu retirei o f antes da string e deixou de dar erro.

Porém começou a dar tambem nesta linha:

```
File "/home/developer/.virtualenvs/store/lib/python3.5/site-packages/minio_storage/storage.py", line 209
    dirs: T.List[str] = []
```

Nunca me deparei com esses erros, meu python está na verao `3.5` e a compatibilidade da biblioteca é `Python 3.4-3.6`. Estes erros de sintaxe são reais? E o que dizer esta expressão se ela existir? `dirs: T.List[str] = []`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apesar da compatibilidade da biblioteca estar marcada como "a partir de 3.4", esse código está usando sintaxe específica de Python 3.6 para cima.

Olhando a página do projeto, no Pypi.python.org, de fato eles se listam como "compatíveis com Python 3.4" - mas trata-se de um erro de manutenção do pacote.

Então, quanto ao primeiro erro - eu nem sabia que de tinha mudado - mas testei aqui e é fato: apesar de Python aceitar uma "," extra sempre que tem uma estrutura separada por vírgulas, no contexto específico de definição de funções, não faz sentido ter qualquer parâmetro depois de um parâmetro marcado com `**` - justamente por que esse é o "coringa" que vai absorver todos os demais argumentos passados em uma chamada. Entao até a versão 3.5, essa vírgula depois do parâmetro começado com "**" gerava um erro de sintaxe. Testei aqui na versão 3.6, e a sintaxe é válida (você vai ter erro se colocar qualquer coisa depois da vírgula - só passaram a permitir a vírgula solta, por que isso acabou virando uma exceção comparado com todos os outros pontos na linguagem em que vírgulas são usados como separadores).

Esse código, e os outros erros que você está obtendo, tem a ver com a sintaxe de "Annotations". 
Desde o Python 3.0 é possível colocar os ":"  `def funcao(nome: Tipo=valor_padrao) -> tipo_de_retorno:` em uma definição de função em Python. Esses valores são objetos de Python que são colocados em um dicionário especial no atributo `__annotations__` de uma função, e não fazem nada *diretamente* no programa, mas podem ser usados como documentação, e por ferramentas externas de verificação de tipos de variáveis.

A partir da versão 3.6 é possível também anotar com tipos as variáveis no corpo de classe e de funções - como a sintaxe onde ocorreu o próximo erro.
A expressão `dirs: T.List[str] = []`  cria ua variável `dirs` com uma lista vazia dentro - `[]`. E junto com isso, cria pra essa variável a anotação `T.List[str]` - essa convenção foi adotada a partir da [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), e indica que essa variável vai conter uma "Lista" cujos elementos devem ser todos "str".  Se o programa de fato faz isso, como dito acima, pode ser verificado por uma ferramenta externa - o "mypy". Sem essa ferramenta, a anotação serve apenas como dica de uso da variável: você bate o olho e já vê que ela deve ser uma lista, e os elementos devem ser string.  (Note que nesse caso específico, o autor do código usou `import typing as T` no começo do arquivo, para poder usar `T.List`, `T.Optional` - em vez de ter que importar individualmente todos os nomes `from typing import List, Optional, Union, ...` - eu adoto essa prática também e acho a melhor solução para o uso de anotações)

## Mas tudo isso, só é válido a partir do Python 3.6

Melhor do que procurar uma versão antiga da biblioteca "minio" que funcione com Python 3.5, é você atualizar o seu projeto para usar um Python mais recente, como a versão 3.8 - estável desde novembro do 2019, ou a 3.7, lançada a quase dois anos já. O Python que acompanha o sistema operacional é o *do sistema*, e não pode ser atualizado sem quebrar tudo - mas ele não tem que limitar suas opções de projeto: você pode instalar versões mais recentes do Python como usuário, e usar [ambientes virtuais](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) para cada projeto. Uma das melhores opções para poder escolher a versão da linguagem é o [PyEnv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), mas há outras, como "snaps" e etc... (se você estiver no Windows, simplesmente instale um Python mais novo).